# Getting error code 28 with cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

**THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED - SEE ANSWER AT THE END OF THIS POST**

I am trying to retrieve data from a remote server using PHP / cURL

If I put the following URL into a browser the data comes back correctly.

http://realm103.c7.castle.wonderhill.com/api/map.json?user%5Fid=5245274&x=375&y=375&timestamp=1310554325&%5Fsession%5Fid=5b2070a46a083a33e053d60dbc2d062e&dragon%5Fheart=098d2deb0a37f18c97428d636c456572f9bade24&version=3

However when I try to access if with PHP / cURL it just times out (error code 28).

```
$json = curl($jsonurl, $realm['intRealmID'], $realm['strRealmServer']);

function curl($url, $realm, $realmServer){
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Host: realm'.strval($realm).'.'.$realmServer.'.castle.wonderhill.com';
$header[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
return curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

}

Anybody have any ideas why it works from the browser but not via cURL? Thanks

ADDITIONAL INFO
Whilst cURL isn't working for the URL above. For the URL below it works just fine. The only difference is the server the data is being requested from. The data itself and POST is identical.

http://realm4.c5.castle.wonderhill.com/api/map.json?user%5Fid=1053774&x=375&y=375&timestamp=1310616808&%5Fsession%5Fid=5b2070a46a083a33e053d60dbc2d062e&dragon%5Fheart=f35f476facab91f0e901eaf2209a0c8a9b9bedcc&version=3

**ANSWER**

Finally back to this and found that the referrer was the problem. The server was expecting to see no referrer in the request header. When it did the request was blocked. That behaviour probably was not consistent across all servers at the time but it is now. Removing the referrer from the request header and leaving everything else the same now works.

Comment: Is there any reason that the user IDs are different in the 2 URLs? Is this because you have 1 for each server? This is unusual as user IDs are usually universal across a single service

Comment: Found the referrer was the issue. I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between your cURL function and requesting the information directly is the `CURLOPT_HEADER` property, I would first try removing this from the code.

Comment: As a side note, try also removing `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`, it shouldn't be a big deal but I would remove it unless absolutely required.

Comment: I tried removing `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` but still no joy. The attempt continues to time out.

Comment: Found that the referrer was the issue. I have updated the OP. Thank you again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function get_data($url)
 {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
 }

 $returned_content = get_data('your url');
```

Alternatively, you can use the `file_get_contents` function remotely, but many hosts don't allow this

```
$userAgent = ‘Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0’;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
```

Some other options I use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

try this:

```
 $ctx = stream_context_create( array(
                 'socket' => array(
                             'bindto' => '192.168.0.107:0',
    )
   ));

   $c= file_get_contents('http://php.net', 0, $ctx);
```

Comment: Thank you for your sugestions. I am testing out the various cURL options now. `file_get_contents` does not work.

I added some extra info to the original question. As the cURL does work for one URL but not for the original one posted. They are however virtually identical. The only exception being the remote server.

Comment: Found the referrer was the issue. I have updated the OP. Thank you again for your help :)